# Calculate total value in table row, JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just learned web design about a month ago, well I am slow learner and lazy, anyway here is my case. I had one row with 5 columns, but i just want to calculate 3 from those columns, here is my `jQuery` code

```
function sumrow(){
$(".isitable").on('keyup','.nsakit, .npuasa, .mnormal', function(){
    var $row=$(this).closest("table tr");
    var jumlahns=parseInt($row.find('.nsakit').val());
    var jumlahnp=parseInt($row.find('.npuasa').val());
    var jumlahmn=parseInt($row.find('.mnormal').val());
    $row.find('.totalqty').val(jumlahns + jumlahnp + jumlahmn);
});}
```

It does work when I am using `<div>`, but when I try to do it by using `<table>`,
is not working at all, `<table class="isitable">` here is part of the table

```
<tbody>   
    <tr id="nmr0" name="roworder">
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="shiftid" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">-Select An Option-</option>
            <option value="Normal Shift">Normal Shift</option>
            <option value="Long Shift">Long Shift</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="breakid" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">-Select An Option-</option>
            <option value="break1">11.45-12.15</option>
            <option value="break2">20.30-21.00</option>
            <option value="break3">18.00-18.45</option>
            <option value="break4">00.00-00.30</option>
            <option value="break5">07.00-07.30</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <div class="rownumber">
    <td>
      <input id="A0" type="text" min="0" class="nsakit" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="B0" type="text" min="0" class="npuasa" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="C0" type="text" min="0" class="mnormal" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="D0" type="text" min="0" class="totalqty" value="">
    </td>
    </div>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="recordi"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

what should i change in my javascript code, to be able calculate total

Comment: Try `var $row=$(this).closest("tr");`

Comment: It seems you missed a bracket in $row.find('.totalqty').val(jumlahns + jumlahnp + jumlahmn);

Comment: you should try with $row=$(this).closest("tr").find('.nsakit').val();

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes it is working now, is it difference when i am using `("table tr")` and`("tr")`?

Comment: @Chidambaram thank you  for correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) *traverses through the ancestors* from the given element in the DOM.

So, when it traverses to the parent element, it checks if the `selector` given as the parameter to `closest` method is matching the element. To match if the row is matching table tr, it needs to traverse further up which is where your selector was failing.

You just need to give `tr` instead of `table tr`

```
var $row = $(this).closest("table tr");
```